# Is running (git reset head~2) equivalent to running (git reset head^) twice?

Tags: git, git-reset

If I have two commits on the local branch, and I run `git reset head^` twice. Will it just undo the two commits, or will I run into problems?

Comment: Note that it's `HEAD`, not `head`.  The latter _may_ work on a machine with case-insensitive filesystems, but only accidentally and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's the same thing and you will just undo the two commits (but keeping the changes).

Note that you could also run `git reset HEAD^^`

Answer (score 2):

`git reset` defaults to [`--mixed`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---mixed) and it will indeed undo the commits keeping the changes in your local tree ("the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit").

As for the revision. While in your described scenario you would get the same behavior, you likely want to say: `HEAD~` and run it twice... or better yet `HEAD~~` or just `HEAD~2`.

This is not uncommon source of confusion, but in short:

- `~` traverses through generations (deeper along a line of first parents)
- `^` traverses across parents of previous generation (mnemonic: circumflex looks like a little fork, you can visit nodes where history forks).

As long as you use them without any numbers, you always get leftmost ancestor with each jump, so `HEAD~~~` and `HEAD^^^` would land you at the same place, `HEAD~2` (two leftmost parents back) is not the same as `HEAD^2` (second from the left parent).

You can see more detail in [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) description including this visual illustration:

> Here is an illustration, by Jon Loeliger. Both commit nodes B and C are parents of commit node A. Parent commits are ordered left-to-right.
>
> ```
> G   H   I   J
>  \ /     \ /
>   D   E   F
>    \  |  / \
>     \ | /   |
>      \|/    |
>       B     C
>        \   /
>         \ /
>          A
>
> A =      = A^0
> B = A^   = A^1     = A~1
> C = A^2  = A^2
> D = A^^  = A^1^1   = A~2
> E = B^2  = A^^2
> F = B^3  = A^^3
> G = A^^^ = A^1^1^1 = A~3
> H = D^2  = B^^2    = A^^^2  = A~2^2
> I = F^   = B^3^    = A^^3^
> J = F^2  = B^3^2   = A^^3^2
> ```

Also, if you are concerned about performing an action, you can always branch off (e.g. `git checkout -b temp`), try your command out, and when happy switch back, delete the temp branch and execute it there.

Comment: The default mode is `--mixed`, not `--soft`.

Comment: @torek Sorry about that, corrected... and with link on top. :)